# Marketing Cloud Email Template: complete with SFDC fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I´m new to the Marketing Cloud, and I am having one issue regarding the templates.

I´m trying to create an HTML template within the Marketing Cloud. I need to send emails to contacts including the contact name in the template (for example: "Hello ##Contact.Name##").

Can anyone help me whit this?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the internet. You should really try to search for your own and come back to ask a question only if you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a personalisation string. The first name / last name fields should be present within the data extension or list you are using to send.

```
Dear %%FirstName%% %%LastName%%,
```

or if you have Name ( a column with the full name),

```
Dear %%Name%%,
```

Answer (score 0):

Data_Kid's approach is correct.  However, this approach requires that the contact information be either in the sending data extension or subscriber attributes in order to be referenced this way.  You can refer to the following online documentation to get you started.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketingcloud_salesforce_integration_v2_non_enterprise_2_0/attributes_for_salesforce_leads_and_contacts_procedures/

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/key_concepts/salesforce_data_extension/